# Searching for letters using Regular expression Java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[]args){

**exp("^[a[k][t][l]]{6}$"); //line 9**
exp("^(bEt).*(oc)$");
exp("^(bEt)$");
exp("^(a).*");
exp("bEt(oc)*");
exp("^(bEt).*");
exp [baba][bebe][bibi][bobo][bubu][fafa][fefe][fofo][fufu]

}

public static void exp(String uttryck){
    int counter = 0;
    File fil = new File("Walta_corpus1.txt");
    Scanner sc = null;
    try{
        sc = new Scanner(fil);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException foo){
    }
    **String word = sc.next();** line 28
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(uttryck);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);



    while(word != null){
        if(matcher.find()){
            counter++;
            System.out.println(word);
            }

        if(sc.hasNext()){
            word=sc.next();
            matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
            }
        else
            word = null;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);

}
```

The problem I need help with is :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at raknare.exp(raknare.java:28)
at raknare.main(raknare.java:9)
```

I´ve tried a lot, but nothing really works..

Comment: My problem is that I don't know which line is line 28. I think highlighting this line will help a lot of people help you :-)

Comment: I suppose it may be the `Scanner sc` which is null because the file is not found. I advise you to print a message in the catch block and to put all following code in the try block.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code :

```
public static void exp(String uttryck) throws FileNotFoundException{
// .....
try{
    sc = new Scanner(fil);
}
catch(FileNotFoundException foo){
    // if scanner throws exception, sc is null
    foo.printStackTrace(); // add this method call and check.
    throw foo; //rethrow exception to caller
}
String word = sc.next(); // if catch is executed, sc will give NullPointerException

//.....
}
```

If you get `FileNotFoundException`, then you will get `NullPointerException` at above line, because you are continuing after catching exception `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Sorry I am not really good at this, but I should put this code between line 28 and down?

Answer (score 0):

You have a NullPointerException on this line :

```
String word = sc.next();
```

Which means your `Scanner sc` is not initialized. It happens if you don't find the file and a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.You can't see if such an exception is thrown because you don't do anything in the catch block.

Try this :

```
public static void exp(String uttryck){
    int counter = 0;
    File fil = new File("Walta_corpus1.txt");
    Scanner sc = null;
    try{
        sc = new Scanner(fil);
        String word = sc.next();**
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(uttryck);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
        while(word != null){
            if(matcher.find()){
            counter++;
            System.out.println(word);
            }

            if(sc.hasNext()){
                word=sc.next();
                matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
            } else
                word = null;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException foo){
        foo.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I think it is a really bad idea to have empty catch blocks. Try to do at least a print to know if you catch an exception.